# How to add iOS Overlay View on first app launch?

Tags: ios, swift, overlay

I would like to add an overlay view on the first launch of my app like in the native iOS apps, e.g. as in this screenshot.
How is that possible? Is there a special class/view for that?

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an **InitialViewController** and do something similar to how I have it implemented on this override method:

Note: My InitialViewController is the first thing to run and there I check if it is the first time the user has opened the app, if it is the first time, I show the modal with the method that I put below, if it is not the first time open, I only show the MainViewController (Or your HomeViewController or another view you want)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // For making the connection with SplashScreenViewController so it could pass data back
    if segue.destination is SplashScreenViewController {
        let vc = segue.destination as? SplashScreenViewController
        vc?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is what my storyboard that contains my views looks like

[image: Main Storyboard]

This is what the first launch of my app looks like

[image: App first launch]

Answer (score 0):

Use `UserDefaults` to store a flag named e.g. "didShowIntro". Don't show the intro when that flag is already set.

The overlay itself looks like a regular `UIViewController` with  modal presentation, i.e. `self.isModalInPresentation = true`